# How do we query a Non-Guest User. (Test Methods failing)

Tags: soql, user, guest-user

How do we query for non Guest users.
with the new Guest Ownership Rules Test methods are failing:
First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception (Guest users cannot be record owners.):

```
User notGuest = [Select Id
    From User 
    Where IsActive = true
    Limit 1];            
acc = new Account(
    Name = 'Test Account',
    OwnerId = NotU.id
);
Insert acc;
```

Answer (score 1):

**userType** Field has these value options (not updateable):

- **Standard**: user license. This user type also includes Salesforce Platform and Salesforce Platform One user licenses. **Label is Standard**.
- **PowerPartner**: User whose access is limited because they’re a partner and typically access the application through a partner portalor Experience Cloud site. **Label is Partner**.
- **CSPLitePortal**: user whose access is limited because they’re an org's customer and access the application through a Customer Portal or Experience Cloud site. **Label is High Volume Portal**.
- **CustomerSuccess**: user whose access is limited because they’re an org's customer and access the application through a Customer Portal. **Label is Customer Portal User**.
- **PowerCustomerSuccess**: user whose access is limited because they’re an org's customer and access the application through a Customer Portal. **Label is Customer Portal Manager**.
  Users with this license type can view and edit data they directly own or data owned by or shared with users below them in the Customer Portal role hierarchy.
- **CsnOnly**: user whose access to the application is limited to Chatter. This user type includes Chatter Free and Chatter moderator users. **Label is Chatter Free**.
- **Guest**: user whose access is limited because they’re an unauthenticated user without login credentials. **Label is Guest**.

**See forth line:**

```
    User notGuest = [Select Id
        From User 
        Where IsActive = true
        AND userType != 'Guest'
        Limit 1];            
    acc = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Account',
        OwnerId = NotU.id
    );
    Insert acc;
```